# PHP Custom Email using PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, session, phpmailer

I am designing an email feature for a client,
the main requirements is to keep user on same page if user has some errors
in email, the errors should be shown on the same page.

For that I have created this HTML (PHP)

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once '../helpers/security.php';

$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PHPmailer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contact">
            <?php if(!empty($errors)): ?>
                <div class="panel">
                    <ul>
                        <li><?php echo implode('</li><li>', $errors); ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <form action="contact.php" method="POST">
                <label>
                    Your Name*
                    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['name']) ? 'value="'.e($fields['name']).'"' : '' ?>>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Your Email*
                    <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off"<?php echo isset($fields['email']) ? 'value="'.e($fields['email']).'"' : '' ?>>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Your Message*
                    <textarea name="message" rows="8"><?php echo isset($fields['message']) ? e($fields['message']) : '' ?></textarea>
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                <p class="muted">* means a required field</p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

unset($_SESSION['errors']);
unset($_SESSION['fields']);

?>
```

And this is my PHP code

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])){
    $fields = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'message' => $_POST['message']
    ];

    foreach($fields as $field => $data){
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[] = 'The '.$field.' field is required';
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
        $m= new PHPMailer;
        $m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth = true;

        /*$m->SMTPDebug = 1; */

        $m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $m->Username = 'mymail@gmail.com';
        $m->Password = 'mypass';
        $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $m->Port = 465;

        $m->isHTML();

        $m->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
        $m->Body = 'From: '.$fields['name'].' ('.$fields['email'].')<p>'.$fields['message'].'</p>';

        $m->FromName = 'Contact';

        /*$m->AddReplyTo($fields['email'], $fields['name']);*/

        $m->AddAddress('mymail@gmail.com', 'My Name');

        if($m->send()){
            header('Location: http://facebook.com');
            die();
        } 
        else {
            $errors[]= 'Error';
        }
    }
} 
else{
    $errors[] = 'something went wrong';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

header('Location: http://google.com');

?>
```

I have added additional security code

```
<?php

function e($string){
    return htmlentities ($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
}

?>
```

I have tried this code but it won't work it gives me "500" server error on the index page as well as contact.php page
I have checked with ";" and other general PHP errors
I have checked just by echoing the variables in PHP (PHP works :P )

On the index page if I remove

```
? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];
```

From

```
$errors = isset($_SESSION['errors']) ? $_SESSION['errors'] : [];
$fields = isset($_SESSION['fields']) ? $_SESSION['fields'] : [];
```

The index page shows form HTML but when I submit the form I get 500 server error on contact.php

Please help me out this code, Thanks in Advanced

Comment: Is your gmail account configured to use less secure clients?

Comment: What *is* the 500 error? Check your error logs.

Comment: "The http://example.com page isn’t working

http://example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
500" in console of inspect elements "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: The real error message will be in your server logs. The 500 error is just safe for public consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the 500 Internal server error:

**A)** Place this snippet right after

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(-1);
```

**B)** If A is not working, try creating a `.htaccess` file in the web-root directory with this in it:

```
php_value error_reporting -1
php_flag display_errors on
```

**C)** If B is not working, then your apache\httpd server does not have AllowOverride enabled. You then should change the php.ini (same as B)

***(one should never do all the above in production. Only use this while developing)***

Now you should be able to see the error, which will be probably that `[]` is not supported by your PHP version.
**Try changing all `[]` to `array()`.**

Comment: If that worked it means you're running an old and unsupported version of PHP.